# Как перенести слова на другую строчку?

Tags: html, css

html

```
<div id="name" align="center">
    {$smarty.const.TABLE_PRODUCT_NAME}
</div>
```

{$smarty.const.TABLE_PRODUCT_NAME} - это функция из движка, строит она соответственно следующий код

```
<a href="#"> длинное слов, с пробелами.... </a>
```

код css

```
#name {
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:60%;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Вёрстка резиновая, ширина должна остаться прежней. пробовал такой вариант, не помогло:

```
a #name {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как ссылки вложены в `#name`,  а не наоборот, то попробуйте:

```css
#name а { 
    white-space: initial;
}
```

Comment: всё равно не хочет переносится.

Comment: У меня две мысли по этому поводу. Не переносится из-за того, что ширина указана в % или из-за того что гиперссылка формируется движком. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: исправил ответ - сейчас должно работать.. а то, как формируется ссылка или в чем указана ширина, роли не играет - http://jsbin.com/xicisepavi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: да, всё отлично. Спасибо огромное)